# Does anyone have a simple word list with types?

Tags: list, dictionary, cpu-word

I'm looking for a word list with types in a simple format like:

```
apple    noun
fast     adjective
```

Does anyone know if such a one exists? I ultimately will be converting this to SQL, so any compatible database/excel format etc. is acceptable too. I don't mind if extra information is present, as long as it will still be easy to parse the data I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to parse one out of [The Online Plain Text English Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20190107022012/http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/%7Eralph/OPTED/) without too much trouble.

Comment: Perfect. I was actually using the same source material, so it's good to see someone's already done some of the parsing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [the Moby Project](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/3203/pg3203-images.html)'s [word list](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3203/files/mobypos.txt).

```
Noun                            N
Plural                          p
Noun Phrase                     h
Verb (usu participle)           V
Verb (transitive)               t
Verb (intransitive)             i
Adjective                       A
Adverb                          v
Conjunction                     C
Preposition                     P
Interjection                   !
Pronoun                         r
Definite Article                D
Indefinite Article              I
Nominative                      o
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.